# Change cell color in html table based on conditions, all data are in table are appended from sharepoint list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to change the color of cells in html based on the conditions I have. For example I have sample table below.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| Status | Name | Company | #ofMonths | Date      | Report |
|--------|------|---------|-----------|-----------|--------|
| Pass   | Bob  |   ABC   |    25     |01/01/2014 |   ###  |
|--------|------|---------|-----------|-----------|--------|
| Fail   | Rob  |   XYZ   |    75     |05/06/2001 |   ###  |
|--------|------|---------|-----------|-----------|--------|
```

Lets say

```
if (#ofMonths < 45) //this condition is working now
```

backgroundColor of the cell [3] should be green

```
if (Date > 01/01/2009 && Date < 01/01/2014) //this is not doing anything
```

backgroundColor of the cell [4] should be yellow

I am appending all the data from sharepoint list. I was able to change the color of "status" and "#ofMonths" column to green, yellow and red based on conditions. I used something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var col_data = $("table tr td");
col_data.each(function(bg, cl) {

   if ($(this).text() == 'fail'){
      $(this).css('background','red');
   }
  if ($(this).text() == 'pass/fail'){
     $(this).css('background','green');
   }
  if ($(this).text()> 36){
    $(this).css('background','red');
   }
  if ($(this).text()>0 && $(this).text()<23){
    $(this).css('background','green');
   }
  if ($(this).text()>27 && $(this).text()<36){
    $(this).css('background','yellow');
  }

});
});
```

For "Date" column I tried add below to in continuation with above code --

```
  if ($(this).text()>01/01/2014){
  $(this).css('background','yellow');
}
```

above code produce no result. if I write the same code pretending date as a string --

```
if ($(this).text()>'01/01/2014'){
  $(this).css('background','yellow');
}
```

it will make all the columns from right of date column to yellow. I just need date column to be yellow.

Everything works fine, I am just not able to change the color of "Date" column based on the data I suck from sharepoint. I have checked many posts here, but nothing seems to working for me, or I couldn't figure out how to do it. 
I have just started working with javascript and already pulling my hairs. Any sort of help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching all the data from SharePoint list then you can use Conditional Formatting on the List Data View through SharePoint Designer.

Comment: I am fetching all the data from SharePoint list and I am using SPServices to do that. I am appending those data to html table and in my page I have only header, footer and a table. No navigational menus nothing, and I am stuck with to use javascript only. Above javascript code I have provided works for status column but I couldn't figure out how to change colors for #ofmonths and date column. I was reading some similar posts and comments where people have suggested to use .val() instead of .text() but it still not working in my case. Any idea?

Comment: Ok let us go step by step. First thing, insert an alert for the "Status", "#ofMonths" and "Date" columns and check what value is coming. Like Status is dropdown (choice) column, so it will include '#;' that is its index.

Comment: Second thing, try passing hard code value instead of using 'each' loop. Third, please provide all the code you are using to apply yellow color to #ofMonths and Date column.  Fourth, do not use 'else' statement, use only 'if' statement and try.   Also provide screen shot of your output. All you got to do is debug step by step by inserting alert at every step where you feel issue is occurring.   Try above steps and let me know.

Comment: I took your advice get rid of 'else' statement and only used 'if' statement and also made date and #ofmonths in separate 'if' statement. Doing this my #ofmonths column start displaying desired colors, but date columns still no result. I have edited my code above. May you take a peak at it when you get a chance? thanks

Comment: Is your date to be compared Static i.e '01/01/2014' if not then take that value in text box and parse it.   var myDate = $('#txtDate').val();

var myDateParsed = Date.parse(myDate);

Comment: You can pass year first then month and day and try. if not working then parse it as shown above or convert it into date format and it will work. var dateToCompare = new Date(year, month - 1, date); Then use that variable in your 'if' statement. You will get lot of content about Date format on google